# KVM/QEMU: cannot attach-device (disk) to a live domain

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

I'm trying to add a new disk to a running guest/domain (Win10)
I succeed in using **virsh attach-disk... --live** and also using **virsh attach-device.. --config**

But using:
`virsh attach-device SRV13 /tmp/SRV13.xml --live`

Give me this error:

> Failed to attach device from /tmp/SRV13.xml
>   internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_add': Property '**virtio-blk-device.drive**' can't find value '**drive-virtio-disk1**'

XML file:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?